# How to vertically align one line or two line text in flex?

Tags: html, css

When using flexbox, I can align things by such css:

```
.crp_related .crp_title {
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: #4E64DD !important;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 1.5;
    flex-flow: unset;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: unset;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 4px 0px;
}
```

The problem is one line text will not go to middle: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8QD7.png

If I use `align-items: center;`, there is another problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtefi.png (If has more than two lines, it globaly centering, and also this is not what I want)

So how do I push one linner into middle?

Comment: Have you tried `vertical-align: middle;`?

Comment: Yes, does not work.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to put the text into a span  - and center that rather than the text.

Here - I am putting `display:flex` on the card footer - and then `margin:auto` on the span inside the footer. This will cause the span to center horizontally (due to the max width) and vertically within the card footer.

```css
.card-wrapper {
display: flex;
}

.card {
 width: 200px;
 border: solid 1px #222;
 margin: 16px;
}

.card-body { 
  height: 100px;
}
  
  .card-body p { 
  text-align: center;
}


.card-footer {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  }
  
  
 .card-footer span{ 
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<div class = "card-wrapper">
 <div class="card">
   <div class="card-body">
     <p> content goes here</p>
   </div>
   <div class="card-footer">
     <span> This is one line of text</span>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="card">
   <div class="card-body">
     <p> content goes here</p>
   </div>
   <div class="card-footer">
     <span> This is two lines of text that will wrap</span>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: crp_title is already an span.

Answer (score -1):

Select that title and use `align-self: center;`
Check more on this -> [MDN align-self](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self)

Comment: I cannot style one item, the titles are not constant. Dynamic changes.